# Не получается убрать заголовок приложения

Tags: android, activity

Пытаюсь убрать в Activity заголовок.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при добавлении метода **requestWindowFeature()** приложение не запускается, выдавая вот такую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если этот метод поставить перед **super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)**, заголовок все равно не исчезает.

Comment: Экстрасенсов тут нема, нужны логи ошибки.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, изменил вопрос, добавил выводимые ошибки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно убрать заголовок в ActionBar - после метода  setContentView() добавить:

```
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }
```

Если нужно убрать ActionBar - лучше наследовать (в styles.xml) свою тему от темы с нужными параметрами:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по [гуглу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21354431/3212712) вам поможет добавление вот этого

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

перед вызовом

> getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);